# Filtering items by their exact title

Tags: python, django

I am trying to filter my items by exact title by clicking on the link with the title. I managed to display the titles, but when I click on one of them I am getting an error: `Reverse for 'category_search' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['search/(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)$']` , which is pointing to the TitleView function.

views.py- Just to clear some things up category_view is used to filter items by their category, which is located on different page, but the results are displayed on search.html

```
def category_view(request, category_id):
  item_list = Item.objects.filter(category__pk=category_id)
  category = Category.objects.get(pk=category_id)

  return render(request, "search.html", {'item_list': item_list, 'category': category})

def TitleView(request, title):
  item_list = Item.objects.filter(title__iexact=title)
  return render(request, "search.html", {'item_list': item_list})

def SearchView(request, category_id=None, title=None):
  if category_id:
      category = Category.objects.get(pk=category_id)
      item_list = Item.objects.filter(category__id=category_id)
  else:
      item_list = Item.objects.all()

  query = request.GET.get('q')
  if query:
      item_list = item_list.filter(title__icontains=query)

  price_from = request.GET.get('price_from')
  price_to = request.GET.get('price_to')

  item_list = item_list.annotate(
      current_price=Coalesce('discount_price', 'price'))

  if price_from:
      item_list = item_list.filter(current_price__gte=price_from)

  if price_to:
      item_list = item_list.filter(current_price__lte=price_to)

  context = {
      'item_list': item_list,
      'category': category,
  }
  return render(request, "search.html", context)
```

html template:

```
    <div class="offset-md-1 col-md-2">
    <h2>Content Filter</h2> <br>
    <form method="GET" action="{% url 'core:category_search' category.id %}">
        <h5>Search</h5>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-8">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border" type="search" name="q"
                        placeholder="Brand..">
                    <span class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h5>Price from</h5>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border" type="search" name="price_from"
                        placeholder="Price from" value="{{request.GET.price_from}}">
                    <span class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h5>Price to</h5>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border" type="search" name="price_to"
                        placeholder="Price to" value="{{request.GET.price_to}}">
                    <span class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-md">Search</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<ul>
    {% for item in item_list %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'core:title_search' title=item.title  %}">
            {{ item.title }}
        </a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

urls:

```
  path('search/', SearchView, name='search'),
  path('search/<int:category_id>', SearchView, name='category_search'),
  path('search/<title>', TitleView, name='title_search'),
  path('bike-category/<category_id>', category_view, name='category'),
```

Comment: How is the title defined on the request? Part of the path, querystring or body of the request.

Comment: @schillingt `http://localhost:8000/search/Rondo%20ruut` Rondo Ruut is the title

Comment: It looks like you're mixing multiple naming conventions for functions, be careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the category in the template's context or use a different template. Given that you're returning a list, I'm not exactly sure how you're going to pull out a category from that.

If you intended this to be a direct link to each of the items, I recommend not using `title` as the searching property. Instead add a SlugField to your model and mark it as unique. Then use that in your url:

```
path('search/<slug:slug>/', item_view, name='item_view'),
```

Then your view would be:

```
def item_view(request, slug):
  item = Item.objects.select_related('category').get(slug__iexact=slug)
  return render(request, "search.html", {
    'item_list': [item],
    'category': item.category
  })
```

Edit:

```
def SearchView(request, category_id=None):
    if category_id:
      category = Category.objects.get(pk=category_id)
      item_list = Item.objects.filter(category__id=category_id)
  else:
      item_list = Item.objects.all()
  title = request.GET.get('title')
  if title:
      item_list = item_list.filter(title__iexact=title)
  else:
     query = request.GET.get('q')
      if query:
          item_list = item_list.filter(title__icontains=query)

      price_from = request.GET.get('price_from')
      price_to = request.GET.get('price_to')

      item_list = item_list.annotate(
          current_price=Coalesce('discount_price', 'price'))

      if price_from:
          item_list = item_list.filter(current_price__gte=price_from)

      if price_to:
          item_list = item_list.filter(current_price__lte=price_to)

  context = {
      'item_list': item_list,
      'category': category,
  }
  return render(request, "search.html", context)
```

urls:

```
 path('search/', SearchView, name='search'),
  path('search/<int:category_id>', SearchView, name='category_search'),
  path('bike-category/<int:category_id>', category_view, name='category'),
```

Template:

```
    <div class="offset-md-1 col-md-2">
    <h2>Content Filter</h2> <br>
    <form method="GET" action="{% if category %}{% url 'core:category_search' category.id %}{% else %}{% url 'core:search' %}{% endif %}">
        <h5>Search</h5>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-8">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border" type="search" name="q"
                        placeholder="Brand..">
                    <span class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h5>Price from</h5>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border" type="search" name="price_from"
                        placeholder="Price from" value="{{request.GET.price_from}}">
                    <span class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h5>Price to</h5>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-5">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border" type="search" name="price_to"
                        placeholder="Price to" value="{{request.GET.price_to}}">
                    <span class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-md">Search</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<ul>
    {% for item in item_list %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% if category %}{% url 'core:category_search' category.id %}{% else %}{% url 'core:search' %}{% endif %}?title={{item.title}}">
            {{ item.title }}
        </a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I think I handled the form's action attribute and the links href attributes properly. You might have to clean them up for your situation.

Comment: In my template after choosing category on different page I got all the items that match chosen category. I can filter them further by title contains and price. I want to be able to filter them by the exact title as well. I have a list that displays all titles that are matching the category and I want to be able to click on the title and filter the items by that. So it would display all the items that matches that title within a category. I dont think that slug is a thing that I am looking for.

Comment: Then you need to include the category for the items that match the title or change your template.

Comment: Ok, how would i do that? Do i need to change the urls as well? Something like that `search/<int:category_id>/<title>` ?. What would I have to add in the views?

Comment: That seems reasonable to me. And I think you can figure it out.

Comment: I take that back. If `title` is a free form text field, then you should make it a query string parameter. Otherwise you're going to run into problems trying to generate links to an item that's title is "what/about/this".

Comment: Never mind again. I didn't realize you had a third view using this same template with a different interface. Yikes. What I suggested probably won't work perfectly either with the generic search.

Comment: What I've included will work, but I think you should have separate views for `search`, `category_search` and this title list view.

Comment: Ok everything works. One more question, Is there a way to display only one type of title? Lets say that I have 2 titles that are the same, can it be display only once instead of twice?

Comment: If you're using postgres, you can use `.distinct('title')` on the Queryset. The other option being to remove any items from the collection that already have the title in the view.

Comment: I am using sqlite, so distinct wont work. How would I go about the second option?  You mean to remove any items with the same title but only in the list of titles right?

Comment: What about a dict where the key is the title and the value is the instance?